# Storing my Survey maker data into salesforce

Tags: api, rest, survey

I have a survey maker tool (proprofs.com/survey). I want that when any respondent respond the survey then the response will save on salesforce. I have already created connected app and connected my platform to salesforce using the REST API. Now I am confused what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of step needed.

- you need to decide in which object you will store data.
- Create a Restful class which can do job of storing your data to sf. when ever a call will be made (survey final click)
- you can call http request to your Restful class and save your data to choice of your object.

there are link which can help you in creating Restful apex class.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST